# CKEditor configured MediaEmbed button doesn't appear in toolbar

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have updated my CKEditor profiles to display the MediaEmbed button. The profile is saved, but when editing content, the button doesn't appear in my toolbar.
I'm using CKEditor 4.4, oEmbed plugin 1.17, jQuery 1.10 and the latest version of the CKEditor module.

Here's a screenshot of the config:
[image: CKEditor module]

And another screenshot of the actual toolbar:
[image: CKEditor toolbar]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve my problem but didn't have time to post it in here. It was simply misconfiguration...

First you need to install Widget, Lineutils and oEmbed plugins in CKEditor's plugin folder.
Then you need to specify the path to the plugins folder in CKEditor's module configuration.
Finally, in each of CKEditor's profile, you need to enable the plugins and move the oEmbed icon to the profile's toolbar.
Clear Drupal and browser cache and it should be working.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:
go to Configuration->Content Authoring->Ckeditor->click on ***Edit*** in *Advanced* or *Full* mode
tick the check box of Plugin for embedding HTML snippets 
and that's it